# Confused by a step in a solution to the problem

Tags: contest-math

I'm pretty confused by the step
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{45}\sin(2n^\circ)=\sum_{n=1}^{45}\frac{\omega^n-1}{2i\omega^{n/2}}
$$

in the [official solution](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h425751p2409488) of this problem from *2010 PUMaC Algebra A7*:

> The expression $\sin2^\circ\sin4^\circ\sin6^\circ\cdots\sin90^\circ$ is equal to $p\sqrt{5}/2^{50}$, where $p$ is an integer. Find $p$.

Can anyone explain this step?

Answer (score 0):

The solutions are publicly available at [this](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h425751p2409488) link. I can put them in MathJax if you really want, but the link is way easier.